# Can't load JSON when loading pages with Ajax and hash url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, handlebars.js

I'm currently working on a project using jQuery and Ajax to load in content from local html files to my single page site. I've also got a JSON file that I'm trying to incorporate into the files being loaded in with jQuery and Ajax.

I'm using hash urls to keep the pages separate. This is the code I'm using:

```
//other cached links
var pageLinks = $(".pageLink");

if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    loadPage(hash + ".html");
} else {
    loadPage("index.html");
}

pageLinks
    .click(function(){
        var iid = $(this).attr("id");
        loadPage(iid + ".html");
    });

function loadPage(resource) {
    window.location.hash = resource.replace(".html", "");
    $.get("pages/" + resource, function (data) {
        content.html(data);
    });
}

//this makes sure the contents of hash in the url is loaded in the page
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    loadPage(hash + ".html");
} else {
    loadPage("index.html");
}
```

This is how I'm putting my JSON data into the page:

```
function FooBar() {
this.foo;
this.barLinkTemplate;
}

var fooBar = new FooBar();

$(document).ready(function (){

fooBar.contentDiv = $("#fooContent");
fooBar.barDiv = $("#bars");

$.when(
    $.getJSON('data/music.json'),
    $.ajax('components/components.html')
).done( function(data, templateData) {
        var templateHTML = $(templateData[0]);

        fooBar.barLinkTemplate = Handlebars.compile( templateHTML.find("#barLinks").html() );

        fooBar.data = data[0].foo;

        fooBar.barDiv.html( fooBar.barLinkTemplate( data[0].bars ));
        ));
    });
```

The Ajax loads just fine, hashes and all. However, nothing from my JSON file is loaded into the page. I think I've narrowed my problem down (at least I hope) to one bit of code. If I comment out the last if/else statement (above), the JSON is loaded in the first page (only the first page). If I click on any link, and I navigate back to that page, the JSON data is gone. I have to actually reload the page for the data to reappear.

Without that if/else statement, I lose the ability to load the page content from the hash in the url--though the links still work fine.

I've been googling, but I haven't seen anything similar to the problems I'm having. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might need to parse that json and than display JSON data.you can have reference from  this link  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Are you trying to console "window.location.hash" this??

Comment: @arjun, I saw .parseJSON around when I was searching for an answer earlier. It's new to me, but I'll keep reading up on it and see if I can get that to work.

Comment: @syms, I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you mean console.log?

Comment: I mean when you comment the if else statement, data is loaded in your index.html, right? if this is the thing it means your if condition not get working properly for this try to console.log(window.location.hash)

Comment: @syms, yes the data will appear on initial load. If I comment out the if/else statement and add the console.log(window.location.hash), I get the correct hash. But once I click on the links, the data disappears until I manually reload the page.

Comment: ok it meance "if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    loadPage(hash + ".html");
} else {
    loadPage("index.html");
}" code is not working when your next page getting loaded. and that's the only reason behind your problem. may I know when you are going to call this code, and also try to debug this with alert or console.log

Comment: @syms, I cache the links right inside of the document.ready statement, and the if/else statement is called directly after that. I do get all alerts/logs that I add in both the if and else.